# Matplotlib 4D data in a 2D array

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a 4D array using as 4th dimension the color. Here is a sample of my matrix:

```
[[ 4.216  0.     1.     0.   ]
 [ 5.36   0.     1.     0.   ]
 [ 5.374  0.     2.     0.   ]
 ..., 
 [ 0.294  0.     1.     0.   ]
 [ 0.314  0.     2.     0.   ]
 [ 0.304  0.     1.     0.   ]]
```

4th column only contains values 0, 1 and 2.

So when I try to plot it using this script:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1],data[:,2], c=data[:,3], cmap=plt.hot())
plt.show()
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: use numpy arrays, not plain lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a 4D array.  It's a 2D array with 4 columns (the 2 dimensions could be referred to as "rows" and "columns").   But I see what you're trying to say—each row could be interpreted as describing a point in 4-dimensional space, with the fourth "dimension" being colour.

Two-dimensionality is actually the key to the problem.  I suspect your `data` variable is a `numpy.matrix` rather than a vanilla `numpy.array`.  A `matrix` is particular class of 2D-array that has various special properties, including the fact that a slice of it (for example, `data[:, 0]`) is ***still*** a 2-dimensional `matrix` object, whereas `.scatter()` expects each argument to be a 1-D array.

The fix is to say:

```
data = numpy.asarray(data)
```

to convert your data from a `matrix` to a normal array whose column slices will be 1-dimensional.

BTW: you probably meant to say `cmap='hot'`.  The call to `plt.hot()` sets the *default* colormap (so your figure may look right, but there's a side effect) but it actually returns `None`.